# AmCharts v4 globe not moving custom markers

Tags: amcharts4

I have a globe map that I'd like to place some markers on, while still allowing users to rotate the map. I found a demo and modified it to use an orthographic projection, and everything looks great - except the custom markers stay stationary  when the user spins the globe! I assume there is some chart event on which I should redraw the markers, but I can't find one in the documentation. Here are the current events:

```
 // add events to recalculate map position when the map is moved or zoomed
    chart.events.on( "ready", updateCustomMarkers );
    chart.events.on( "mappositionchanged", updateCustomMarkers );
```

If you resize the map, the markers move accordingly, just not when panning.

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/1cxwyvpb/1/

Comment: That's not Highmaps, that amCharts: Maps. I've retagged the question.

Comment: Ack! Good catch, thanks. I've been comparing products and switched up the names!